# Return websocket from signalR in ASP .NET 3.0

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, websocket, signalr

Im trying to complete this Task for interview. Task look like this:

Create REST API.Following endpoints needs to be implemented:

POST /login
• In POST payload will be username and password and it returns false or true with some token

GET /leaderboards/
• Returns dummy data for some game typesGET

/matches
• Returns dummy list of active matchesPOST

/match/join
• **Player will join into the match and it returns WebSocket connection with some session tokenWS** /match/room
• **This endpoint is only for WebSocket**

• There will be three messages: Fire (void), Move (Vector3 Location), GetPlayers (uint16 Limit)All routes should return only dummy data, no database is necessary (but its bonus if you will have time to implemented some database). Please use .NET Core, C# and. ASP.NET Core. **For WebSocket please use SignalR**.

**I cant get on how to create websocket with signalR and how to get its data session token.
Can anybody explain it to me?**

All i could come up with is creating a hub like this:

```
 public class MatchHub: Hub
    {
        public async void Fire()
        {
           await Clients.All.SendAsync("Fire msg");
        }
        public async void Move (Vector3 Location)
        {
           await Clients.All.SendAsync("Move msg");
        }
        public async void GetPlayers (UInt16 Limit)
        {
           await Clients.All.SendAsync("GetPlayers msg");
        }
    }
```

but i dont think thats what they want. And as much as i understand this hub is avaible always and there for no Join method is needed.

Comment: SignalR is an abstraction over WebSockets that also falls back to older transports when necessary, i.e. you use SignalR you don't implement or use the WebSockets protocol directly.

Comment: "I cant get on how to create websocket with signalR"... SignalR will create a websocket automatically for you whenever you initiate a SignalR connection (unless it can't for any reason, in which case it will try to use a different protocol instead). If you'd spent 2 minutes to read any basic intro to SignalR you'd know that already. So this instruction is simply telling you to use SignalR for your websocket implementation, and not to use any other implementation of websockets. Therefore I'd say your approach creating a SignalR hub is basically ok. (For "session token", just use connection ID.)

Comment: Adyson, I spent more time than you probably think on reading about SignalR (few hours actually) and I understood all you are writing. That is why I created this question. I was not sure if I understood it correctly. And was thinking that the task requires me to use websockets directly which actually is not possible with signalR. It was just my insecurity in my knowledge.

Comment: @Genna: So what is your current question/issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@mm8: Well the answer is that you cannot open websocket from controller using signalR(it opens by itself on startup hub configuration). And there for can't use it as they want in task. I think what I have done with hub is after all the correct way. And just to return session data I used SignalR.Client nugget like this:

```
[HttpGet("match/join", Name = "JoinMatch")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> JoinMatch()
        {  
            var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("http://localhost:5000/match/room")
                .Build();

            await connection.StartAsync();
            await connection.SendAsync("Fire");

            return Ok(connection);
        }
```